# Eclipse cannot find any api

Tags: android, eclipse

I update the Android SDK yesterday with the lastest API's. After this my Eclipse doesn't work properly and cannot find any API. I checked the SDK path in my IDE and that's ok, but the Window/Preferences/Android list is totaly empty. That means i cannot generate R.java, import any library like google play services. I've just tryed to updte the Eclipse and it doesn't.

Thak's in advanced!!!
Jota

Comment: I had also a big issue updating SDK to latest version. It ended up by deleting everything and installed toally new. It seems the new Android L Api update do have some bug or incompatibillity

Comment: Ok, i will try to delete the Android SDK and the Eclipse IDE. Thaks.