# Project Build Target not available - android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have recently updated android sdk tools to v23.0.2 in eclipse, 
after that it is not showing any targets in project properties and it is asking to update android adt to v23.x.x. After checking for updates it is still showing adt needs to be updated please help.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gRqq.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDjdy.png)

Comment: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/phqTa.png) 

[link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IXTxm.png)

Comment: Same issue.....need complete resinstall. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839412/eclipse-cannot-find-any-api

Comment: thanks after reinstall it worked